# How covert function to listview?

Tags: python, django

This is my code,
I use django v3 and want convert the category functions in views.py to a list class(ListView) for use pagination.
How can do it?
Thank you alot

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path from .views import  posts_category
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('<slug:slug>/', posts_category, name="posts_category"),
    
    ]
```

model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=90, unique=True)
    description = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="imgs")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['title']
```

views.py

```
def posts_category(request, slug):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    post = Posts.objects.filter(category__slug=slug, status="p")
    context = {
        'category': category,
        'post': post,
    }
    return render(request, 'posts_category.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good idea to show categories and products in the same page (because of the performance point of view) but you can use following code to convert your FBV to CBV:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView


class PostCategoryView(ListView):
    template_name = 'posts_category.html'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return Posts.objects.filter(category__slug=slug, status="p")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

And also change your `urls` to:

```
from django.urls import path 
from .views import  PostCategoryView
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('<slug:slug>/', PostCategoryView.as_view(), name="posts_category"),
    
    ]
```

And finally you can use the context data in your template like the following code:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {{ obj.id }} - {{ obj.name }}</a><br>
    {% endfor %}
```

Note that `object_list` is a list of your Post objects and you should change `obj.name` to other fields of your Post model. Finally you can use something like `object_list` (here we used `categories`) and loop through it to show the data of your categories or other things.